# How to programatically solve the optimal control problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory

I have to **programatically** (write a program) find a control function $u(\cdot)$ to minimize the following functional:

$$ J(u,x) = \int_0^T { f_0(x(t), u(t), t)}dt + \Phi(x(0)) \rightarrow \min$$

Where $x$ and $u$ should satisfy this Cauchy problem:
$$\begin{cases}
{dx \over dt} = A(t)x(t) + B(t)u(t) \\
x(T) = x_T = const
\end{cases}$$
In which:
$$ A(t) = \left(\begin{matrix} a_{11}(t) & a_{12}(t) \\ a_{21}(t) & a_{22}(t) \end{matrix}\right), \quad B(t) = \left(\begin{matrix} b_{11}(t) & b_{12}(t) \\ b_{21}(t) & a_{22}(t) \end{matrix}\right),\quad x = \left(\begin{matrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t)\end{matrix}\right)$$

I thought about using Pontryagin's Maximum Principle, but it's too hard to implement with c++ or python and not nessesary in my task.

Can someone please suggest me a nice and easy to implement method (or algorithm) to solve this?

Comment: Does $f$ have any special properties? Typically you specify a functional form for the optimization functional.

Comment: Since your problem is quite small (2 states, 2 control inputs), I think this should be doable still with dynamic programming (probably go for A* or LCA implementations of it). Have you thought/tried that? Also do $A(t)$ etc. have any special structure? i.e. are they linear w.r.t. $t$?